# How create a graph of profit over time

Tags: numbers, graph

I have created a spreadsheet on numbers to track profit/loss of cryptocurrency investments. I have taken the data for the current value of the cryptocurrency using stock quote so it updates every few minutes. I have a total profit amount at the bottom of the spreadsheet that changes as the figures do. I’d like to create a line graph that shows the profit going up and down over time. I’m not sure how to make the x axis correspond to a date and how to link this with the profit, I don’t really want it to update every few minutes as the figures do but possibly once daily. Can anyone help please? [image]

Answer (score 1):

To create a graph of profit over time, you need data over time. Spreadsheets can only plot graphs of data present in a table, or interpolated between. That means you need a table containing rows for each time point you want plotted, not just the current value.

Numbers can import [‘delimited or fixed-width text files’](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/numbers-ipad/tan9f3c54bdc/ipados). If you can find a source for the data you need over time, you can import this into Numbers and plot the data over time.

Create one row for each point in time over a contiguous time period with regular interval and use a line graph, or plot using a scatter graph for non-contiguous/non-regular time (other types cannot be used, see [Time as x-axis in chart with Apple Numbers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/282071/37797)).